# Does swfmill embed or load images

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe, swfmill

I was curious to know if **swfmill** actually embeds image's into the `swf` or creates a loader?

In the [documentation](http://www.swfmill.org/doc/using-swfmill.html#introduction) it says "Add to Library".

but in [examples](http://haxecasts.com/video_casts/adding-images-to-your-haxe-project-using-swfmill) I see the author importing `flash.display.LoaderInfo;` and using bitmaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets are embedded and not dynamically loaded. In the example you mention there is an `import` but it is actually not used.